# Memory-Mapped files in c# web application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web application reading content from embedded JSON files sometimes twice or thrice from a single call by the user but not necessarily updated. The calls are sequential meaning each all gives information that helps narrow down to values containing piece of information the users require.

My challenge is that with a small number of users, the IO calls are negligible but when the numbers increase to say 100, this part of the code becomes a bottleneck.

Is it possible to use Memory-Mapped Files so that the file is loaded to memory and then all calls reference it? All examples I have seen after extensive searching are of mostly desktop applications which on-boot can load a file to memory, however, being a web application, our entry points are usually controllers.

I'm grateful in advance for all insights

Comment: That doesn't help, files are already memory-mapped by the file system cache.  The cost is in opening the file, takes about 20 msec on a spindle disk.  Two seconds is something you'll see.  So open the file just once, ideally you store the json info in a class.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. The json file contains unstructured data depending on different services because it gives me the flexibility on loading new services without much effort. Would your suggested approach still work?

Comment: That's hopelessly vague.  JSON data is just a string, a string doesn't have any structure either.

Comment: I'm new to C# so pardon my ignorance. Let me implement a singleton and see how that works. Thanks